# Opening an html page that is written inside a .bat in Chrome?

Tags: html, batch-file

Probably a simple answer and I'm over thinking it. Trying to write all html, css, JS code inside a batch file. When you get through the batch code and it opens the html page, it opens it in what I can imagine is a system default program. **I want it to open in Chrome**. This isn't my project, but an example I wrote up to better help you guys help me. (:

```
<!-- :: Batch section
@echo off

:login

color 2

echo= & echo                            This will be the batch login screen & echo =--------------------- & echo login to continue.. & echo =---------------------

@echo off

set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$uword = read-host 'Username' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($uword); ^
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%u in (`%psCommand%`) do set username=%%u
if %username%==admin goto :passwordprom

color 4

echo Incorrect Username!

pause

goto :login

:passwordprom

set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Password' -AsSecureString ; ^
$BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if %password%==123 goto :opengui1

color 4

echo Incorrect Password!

pause

goto :passwordprom

:opengui1

@echo off


for /F "delims=" %%a in ('mshta.exe "%~F0"') do set "HTAreply=%%a"
echo End of HTA window, reply: "%HTAreply%"

exit
-->

<!--HTML Section-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
        <p>need to get this page to open in Chrome</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Of course if you'd like to run this, copy paste it into a .bat file and run it as such. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is the MicroSoft HTA, ,(mshta.exe), which instantiates the Internet Explorer HTML rendering engine, plus any language engines, _usually `.dlls`_, capable of doing so in Chrome?